# Command update-alternatives --config java change nothing

Tags: java

I want to switch my java version with the command update-alternatives --config java, but I don't see any changes after that.
I'm using that command and have this output:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config java
There are 2 choices for the alternative java (providing /usr/bin/java).

Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      auto mode
  1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java      1111      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1081      manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```

Before it I have used Java 8 and selection was set on /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java. Then I switched, run java -version and have the same version as it was - Java 8:

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_212"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.212.04.1 (build 1.8.0_212-b04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Corretto-8.212.04.1 (build 25.212-b04, mixed mode)
```

I changed JAVA_HOME and PATH to use Java 11, but it still changed nothing:

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/user9679/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/home/user9679/.sdkman/candidates/gradle
/current/bin:/home/user9679/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/ 
bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/
```

Comment: You seem to be using https://sdkman.io/ Do you want to stop using sdkman and move to the "update-alternatives" system?

Comment: @Joni you are the best of the best, thank you. I have deleted sdkman and its all works

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have made a change in your system that prevent `update-alternatives` to work.

---

### Expected behavior

As I know, in a typical installation, the `java` command is a symbolic link in `/usr/bin/java`. You must exclude the "real" java path from the `$PATH` variable. If your computer use a `java` command in a different directory, the `update-alternatives` will not work.

```
-- location of the java command
$ type -p java
/usr/bin/java

-- real location of the java command
$ readlink -f /usr/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

If you get a different result for the `type -p java` command, you must check if the location of the `java` command is determined by some folder in the `$PATH` and remove that part.

---

**NOTE:** You may define the JAVA_HOME variable [processing the `/usr/bin/java` symbolic link](https://askubuntu.com/a/728723).

```
-- real location of the JAVA_PATH variable
$ dirname /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/

$ dirname /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/

-- setting the JAVA_HOME variable
$ export JAVA_HOME=`type -p java|xargs readlink -f|xargs dirname|xargs dirname`
```